# keyboard in tty behaves wrong after login as root

Tags: 14.04, bash, keyboard, root

I am not sure if it's the keyboard layout or what.

after

```
 sudo su
```

the keyboard doesn't work correctly. For example there is no letter *'i'* or '*.'*

It really troubles that I can't use *i*. Can't even paste it. "exit" contains an "i", so I tried "logout":

```
logout
bash: logout: not login shell: use `exit'
```

However, when logged in as user the keyboard behaves correct.
My problem is not that I can't logout.

The problem is, that I want my *i* back. I've read that it could make sense to check $LANG

```
$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
$ sudo su
[sudo] password for sadik: 
root@-$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

Here is the content of /root/.bashrc

```
$ sudo cat /root/.bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi
```

Comment: you can logout with CTRL+D

Comment: My guess is that you are using different locale for your regular user, but root is in `en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: Serg might be right. I am not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Try `loadkeys <layout>`, where `<layout>` is one of the keyboard layouts in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/`. Not sure where the problem stems from, but this may fix it.

Comment: thanks, but that didn't work. my "i" is still not working as root.

Comment: Ok, can you post the content of `/root/.bashrc`? It may be that something there is overriding the keymapping.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: There could be something in the root user's ~/.inputrc, or possibly in /etc/inputrc that maps i to something. Please try renaming both files. If it eliminates the problem, include the files to enable further inspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be something in the root user's ~/.inputrc, or possibly in /etc/inputrc that maps i to something.

These files are not regular scripts, they have a subset language that can be used to change key bindings. Googling "inputrc" can provide some examples. Be careful though, it's easy to mess up key bindings and get a non functional terminal.

When things go wrong, renaming both files (in your GUI, if terminal is unresponsive) should eliminate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

laugh suggested in a comment to rename /etc/inputrc.
That solved the problem. So I checked the reason.

At the end of the file /etc/bash_completion was called

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

the file directed me to another file:

```
. /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
```

the files header:

```
#                                                          -*- shell-script -*-
#
#   bash_completion - programmable completion functions for bash 4.1+
#
#   Copyright © 2006-2008, Ian Macdonald <ian@caliban.org>
#             © 2009-2013, Bash Completion Maintainers
#                     <bash-completion-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
#
#   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2, or (at your option)
#   any later version.
#
#   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#   GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#   along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#   Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA.
#
#   The latest version of this software can be obtained here:
#
#   http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/
#
#   RELEASE: 2.1
...
```

On the website it says

> We're currently working to get bash-completion at its best.

Well, try harder. Deleting the mentioned files solves the problem. Thank you laugh.

Comment: Good to hear  it worked. I posted it as an answer in case you want to grant the bounty :-)

Comment: Thx. Unfortunately it also removes my bash completion. I will need to fix this myself, I guess.

Comment: Try [bash completion tutorial](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4738/an-easy-bash-completion-tutorial).